# What is the calculation of net asset value of my brokerage account

Tags: brokerage, balance

In my brokerage account, is my total account balance (cash + equities) the same as the net asset value of the account?

Or is there a difference?

Comment: What does your brokerage say about this? Do they tell you what the net asset value of your account is, and you wish to verify this calculation? Or do you want to keep track of this in your own personal balance sheet?

Comment: I want to make sense of the jargon...if NAV is same as account balance, then it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*is my total account balance (cash + equities) the same as the net asset value of the account?*

1. yes

*is there a difference?*

2. no